# How to hide certain characters within an html input list?

Tags: javascript, css, html, input, datalist

I have an html input list, with an associated datalist, defined as follows:

```
<input list="mylist" id="my-input" name="friend-name" 
   placeholder="Begin typing friend's name here..." 
   required class="form-control">
```

The list itself (and the associated datalist) is working fine. However, each of my entries are of the form: `"String [numeric_id]"`

- What I am wondering is if there is any way that I can somehow hide
  the `[numeric_id]` part before the form is submitted.
- I have looked at the pattern attribute, but that seems to limit the
  actual data allowed in the input, which isn't what I want - I just
  want the part between square brackets [] to be hidden, but still
  submitted to the form.
- It would be ok to move it to another input of `type=hidden` as well.
  Is there any possible way to do that?

@isherwood, here is my form tag:

```
<form action="/chat_forwarding/modal_edit_msg.php" id="fwd-form" method="POST" class="form-inline" style="display: block;">
```

Comment: Certainly. How are you submitting the form?

Comment: Is there a 1-to-1 relationship between strings and IDs? If so, why do you need both of them, isn't it redundant?

Comment: no, it's not a 1-to-1 relationship. The strings are names of users, which could possibly be repeated, but the ids within brackets are unique. That's why I need both. Let me add my form tag to the question.

Comment: @isherwood - I added my form tag to the question above. If there's any further info I can provide, please let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have mentioned that my input is also using Awesomplete (and jQuery). For this reason, binding normal events like keyup did not work (the event would fire whenever a user typed a key). I was able to achieve the functionality I wanted with the awesomplete-selectcomplete event as follows (this will add a hidden input element with value of the id from a string of the form "String [id]"):

```
  $("#my-input").on('awesomplete-selectcomplete',function(){
        var fullStr = this.value;
        //alert(fullStr);
        var regex = /\[[0-9]+\]/g;
        var match = regex.exec(fullStr);
        //alert(match[0]);
        if (match != null) // match found for [id]
        {
                var fullName = fullStr.substr(0,fullStr.lastIndexOf("[")-1);
                var x = match[0];
                var id = x.substr(1, x.lastIndexOf("]")-1);
                //alert(id);
                $('#fwd-form').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="h_uid" value="' + id + '">');
                $('#my-input').val(fullName);


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using any framework that support binding, you should listen to input events and update a hidden input based on that.

This is a function that may give you the idea:

```
let realInput = document.getElementById('real-input');
let userInput = document.getElementById('user-input');
userInput.addEventListener('input', function(value) {
  const inputValue = value.target.value;
  realInput.value = inputValue; // update the hidden input
  const userInputResult = inputValue.match(/\[[^\[]*\]/); // the regex for [numberic_id]
  if (userInputResult) {
    userInput.value = inputValue.substring(0, [userInputResult.index - 1]); // -1 is to remove the space between the 'string' and the '[numeric_id]'
  }
});
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm using Awesomplete and jQuery. I was able to come up with a solution which I've now posted in case it's useful to anyone else.